# Flutter : Stick the scrollbar the side of the screen and not the side of the Wrap widget

Tags: flutter, scrollbar

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Wrap(
      children: [
        
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

With this code, a Scrollbar will appear on the right side of the Wrap widget. I'd like that scrollbar to stick to the side of the screen instead of the side of the Wrap widget.
This can be achieved by wrapping the Wrap widget with a SizedBox the size of the screen, but I'd like a more 'elegant' solution :

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```